# sys.indexes composite key showing a NULL HEAP Row. Expected?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a Unique NC index on a table, and when I look at it via `sys.indexes` I see two rows.

Is this expected?

I need to identify the PK for an ETL like process.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(‘MyTable’)
```

Output is pivoted for your viewing pleasure.

```
object_id           4       5  
name                NULL    PK_SchedName_LineNo 
index_id            0       6 
type                0       2 
type_desc           HEAP    NONCLUSTERED    
is_unique           0       1 
data_space_id       2       2 
ignore_dup_key      0       0 
is_primary_key      0       1
```

DDL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Acc_ Schedule Line](
    [Seq] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Schedule Name] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SchedName_LineNo] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [Schedule Name] ASC,
        [Line No_] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
    , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
) ON [Primary]
GO
```

Comment: Yes because the raw table, in your case a heap, is also considered an index. Read some of Brent Ozar writings on indexes.

Comment: That's an interesting "pivot" -- are you saying `MyTable` has `object_id` 4 and 5 at the same time somehow? In general, though, yes, this is exactly what you expect to see for a table with a non-clustered primary key. You specified no clustered index, so it's a heap table.

Comment: Just to clear up a couple of common misconceptions: An `Unique Index` or `Unique Constraint` is not the same as a `Primary Key` - in technical terms, they could be the table's primary key, or they could be what are called "candidate keys", keys that also uniquely identify each row, but are not the Primary Key.  Also, none of these are necessarily `Clustered indexes` - one of them can be, but a clustered index is not mandatory. And, if a table does not have a clustered index, in SQL Server it is considered a Heap, and shows up with index id zero.

Comment: Thank you excellent responses and I'm sheepishly thinking to myself - you know that. LOL